# Unable to add ultimate power plan

Tags: windows-10, power-management

I used to be able to follow this article to get Ultimate Power Plan by following this article:
https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/110372-restore-missing-default-power-plans-windows-10-a.html
but this is no longer the case for NEW windows installations. All laptops which were already configured to show this plan before still show this, but new laptops with clean windows 10 install no longer show the Ultimate power plan no matter what I do. Any suggestsions?

I am running Windows 10 pro version 2004
thanks

Comment: What error do you receive?  Please be as specific as possible and indicate exactly what happens.  I was unable to reproduce this problem on my 2004 VM

Comment: The old style multiple power plans has been largely removed (may depend on manufacturer) and was replaced with a comprehensive group of settings in Start, Settings, System -> Battery

Comment: The issue is Connected Standby: https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/h0z1vo/win_10_2004_power_plans_are_gone/

Comment: so no errors whatsoever - all positive responses from commands but nothing happens. In terms of this being largely replaced, I have read some people saying it online, but I didn't see any Microsoft article about it. I'll take a look at the Connected Standby link. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

thank you for all the replies. The link to Connected Standby from Ramhound explained it all. The official name of the feature which took away power plans is modern standby (which hasn't worked for me well since windows forced it a few months ago). this now explains several issues I have been having as of lately. Thank you